# Interpreting a statement with a negative quantifier

Tags: logic

In "Mathematics and the Real World" by Z. Artstein a sentence is stated:

*There is no head injury too minor for you to ignore.*

Throughout the text, the author expresses reservations regarding quantifies, especially negative ones.

I would (incorrectly in the eyes of the author) interpret the medical directive to have every head injury checked out.

Yet the author claims the sentence expresses the opposite, further supporting his thesis that "the brain has difficulty in analyzing [statements] that contain a negative."

So what is the correct interpretation of the italicized sentence?

Thanks

Comment: I agree with your interpretation.  I am a native English speaker, and I can't imagine a different interpretation.  I can think of somewhat similar statements that are ambiguous.  "We can't do too much" might mean "we must avoid doing too much" or it might mean "it is impossible to do too much", but I would say that this is because of an idiomatic use of the phrase "we can't" to counsel avoidance.

Comment: As a non-native speaker, I'd say there is something funny here: a head injury can either be *too major to be ignored* or *sufficiently minor to be ignored*. Yet, when a *There isn't* is anteposed, the two forms mix together into *There is no head injury too* **minor** *to be ignored*. However, I don't know my double negations too well: for instance what *too minor not to be ignored* is supposed to mean and how you are supposed to change the form when the sentence is subordinate to a negative verb.

Comment: Yes, there is more to this statement than what seems obvious at first. See @lemontree below. To me, it seems the inconsistency stems from the ambiguity of natural language and not the use of quantifiers or negations, so I don't understand the author's critique against formal languages. Formal languages are intended to remove the ambiguity inherent in natural language. If what he means is to avoid the use of superfluous negations, then yes, I would agree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The misinterpretation can be derived from an analogy to examples like

> No beverage is too cold to drink

which would intuitively be interpreted as

> Any beverage, no matter how cold it is, can be drunk.

Applying the same paraphrasing to the sentence

> No head injury is too minor to ignore

-- which is syntactically completely identical to the first one -- leads to the author's claim

> Any head injury, no matter how minor it is, can be ignored.

Of course one could switch things around and claim that the logical paraphrase of

> No head injury is too minor to ignore

is

> No head injury, no matter how minor it is, can be ignored

but this just shifts the problem because then

> No beverage is too cold to drink

becomes

> No beverage, no matter how cold it is, can be drunk

So in any case, we get an inconsistency. Luckily, the human brain is sophisticated enough to be able to figure out the intended interpretation for these to particular sentences so the problem might not seem obvious at first, but the inconsistency is there, and it is not difficult to imagine that there could be sentences whose intended interpretation is indeed unclear, as both (completely opposite) readings are in principle possible as can be seen from the examples. This is why the author concludes that "the brain has difficulty in analyzing [statements] that contain a negative."

(Personally I find that more "logical", direct paraphrase of "No X is too Y to Z" is indeed "Any X, no matter how Y it is, can be Z", which gives the head injury sentence the undesired interpretation -- but the sentence and its intended interpretation does not at all seem unnatural on first sight as the comments to your answer prove, which is precisely what seems to confirm the point that natural language does not always behave "logically".)

---

Re. your comment:
It is true that "ignore" has an implicit negation in its semantics, but this doesn't solve the problem. Paraphrase "ignore" as "not treat" to make the negation visible. If we want to avoid

> Any head injury, no matter how minor it is, can be not treated

and instead end up with

> Any head injury, no matter how minor it is, should be treated

how could we justify that 180° turn in which the negation just magically disappeared? If we were to establish a rule that cancels out any implicit negations in the Z part ("not treat" --> "treat"), we again just shifted the problem, because then we also have translate

> No expired meat is too tasty to be avoided

-- in which "avoid" is an implicitly negative word that can be paraphrased as "not eat" -- as

> Any expired meat, no matter how tasty it is, can be eaten

with the negatoin cancelled away, which is not what we want -- wheras the translation we used for the beverage sentence gives us the right meaning, namly

> Any expired meat, no matter how tasty it is, is to be avoided

So again, no matter how we twist and turn things, our interpretations are inconsistent, and that is exactly the problem.

Comment: I appreciate your kind answer. And I know it is proper etiquette to accept an answer. If I may, I am still contemplating your answer and maybe by tomorrow I can better articulate or resolve what I'm puzzling about: primarily the notion that while both drink and ignore are transitive verbs, drink is a positive action, whereas ignore has a connotation of not acting. With regards,

Comment: @user663837 I updated my post.